# Android listview onclicklistener with dynamic buttons

Tags: android, listview

I built a listview that displays dynamic buttons with the name of tables in a database.  When a person clicks the button it's supposed to grab the text of the button and then pass that to the next activity which would populate the information corresponding to the database table and display that text at the top of the screen.  The code I've written keeps crashing when I click the button.  Is there something else I need to call or does this code not work with a button?

```
public class UserArea extends AppCompatActivity {

SectionListAdapter sectionListAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

TextView tvWelcomeMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcome);

/**Get Sections and Display as buttons*/
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSections);
sectionListAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(this, R.layout.section_layout);
listView.setAdapter(sectionListAdapter);

Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
            /** If data successfully gathered*/
            if (success) {

                JSONArray jsonArray= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Flights");

                int count = 0;

                String flight;

                while(count<jsonArray.length()) {

                    JSONObject SL = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                    flight = SL.getString("Flight");

                    SectionList sl = new SectionList(flight);
                    sectionListAdapter.add(sl);

                    count++;

                }

            }
            /** If data is not gathered*/
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserArea.this);
                builder.setMessage("Failed to connect")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
        /** if any other response is received*/
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

/**Creates Request to get the data*/
GetSectionRequest getSections = new GetSectionRequest(responseListener);
/**Creates a queue to run the code*/
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserArea.this);
queue.add(getSections);

/**End*/

/**Creates onclicklistener to pass clicked section name*/

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

      Intent intent = new Intent (UserArea.this, Personnel.class);
      intent.putExtra("section", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
      UserArea.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

SectionListAdapter

```
public class SectionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public SectionListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }


    public void add(SectionList object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        row = convertView;

        SectionListAdapter.SectionListHolder sectionListHolder;

        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_layout, parent, false);
            sectionListHolder = new SectionListAdapter.SectionListHolder();
            sectionListHolder.bSection = row.findViewById(R.id.bSectionName);

        }else{

            sectionListHolder = (SectionListAdapter.SectionListHolder)row.getTag();

        }
        SectionList SectionList = (SectionList) this.getItem(position);
        sectionListHolder.bSection.setText(SectionList.getFlight());



        return row;
    }

    static class SectionListHolder{

        Button bSection;
    }
}
```

Log Cat

```
10-10 19:31:26.797 6595-6595/com.example.yikes.recall E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yikes.recall, PID: 6595
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.Button com.example.yikes.recall.SectionListAdapter$SectionListHolder.bSection' on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you please post more code or the error log?

Comment: this will answer your question **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.Button com.example.yikes.recall.SectionListAdapter$SectionListHolder.bSection' on a null object reference** maybe the layout of your **bSection** is not found in your layout, try to double check you xml layout.

Comment: @Jerrol bSection is in SectionListAdapter where the buttons are supposed to be stored, maybe I built that wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I'm try code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(listView);

        final String[] activities = new String[]{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (String item : activities) {
            adapter.add(item);
        }


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("item", item);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

It's working, I think

```
/**Creates Request to get the data*/
GetSectionRequest getSections = new GetSectionRequest(responseListener);
/**Creates a queue to run the code*/
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserArea.this);
queue.add(getSections);
```

Need some time, you can add ProgressDialog when start app and dismiss when response callback. Hope it can help you!

Comment: I've added the code that i used to populate the ListView.  I can add the adapter to if that would help.

Comment: I will try this after I get off work, also does this need to be placed into the response.listener?  I'm pulling the tables from an online sql database.

Comment: When you get data from sql, connection need time connect and query. Please try and feedback to me.

Comment: I tried the code as you put it and it does work, however I'm confusing myself on placing the sql data into that adapter. I've put my SectionListAdapter above.

Comment: through reading I think  i need to edit the getView in the adapter I've made.

Comment: Yes. Maybe reason from getView in Adapter.